# how to pick a encrypted image - android

Tags: android, cryptography

I'm trying to make an image encrypter and it goes like this : 
I'm choosing the image from the gallery with

```
Intent i = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
i.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(i,0);
```

and I go to the gallery and i get the images and i can choose an image and view it in `imageView` it's okay .. the problem is when i do the same thing and i want to pick the encrypted image because it's encrypted the app can't identify this as an image so it crash and give me `NullPointerException` 
so what i want is how to get a path for a file for example i encrypt an image and save it as ima.jpg in sd card how can i just choose the image to get the path of it i just want the path .. in other words i want to choose a file and get the path of it.

Comment: What do you mean by `encrypted image`?

Comment: I encrypt an image using AES algorithm so when i take an image it will be a normal image when i encrypt it using AES i encrypt all the bytes so it will no longer be valid as an image

Comment: You have to decrypt the image before you can read it as image.

Comment: you're right but the question is how to choose it and decrypt .. for example i sent an encrypted  image for you. you have to enter to my app and choose the image to decrypt in other words you have to put the path so the app can go and decrypt the data

Comment: You sent me an image. I saved it somewhere, say in `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`. Then I have to reopen it from the same path.

Comment: yeah how you gonna choose it ?

Comment: Something like `appPath = String.format("%s/yourApp/image.enc", Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());`

Comment: Okay how to pick it from the Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()); i want to pick the file not typing a static path

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html